# Method of coefficients quotient variable power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Divide $15+2m^4-31m+9m^2+4m^3+m^5$ by $3-2m-m^2$

I use the method of coefficients. I first arrange the dividend and divisor coefficients in descending powers then proceed to the operation:

$-1, -2, 3$ $
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4 &9&-31 &15 \\
1 & 2 & -3 \\
 &  & 7 &9&-31& \\
 &  & 7 &14&-21 \\
 &  &  &-5&-10 &15 \\
 &  &  &-5&-10 &15 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$ $-1,-7,5$

The quotient coefficients are $-1, -7, 5$. Since the entire operation is in descending order of powers, I naturally assumed the quotient is $-m^2-7m+5$. But it isn't. The correct quotient is $-m^3-7m+5$. Here is my question. How can I tell what the correct power is? Obviously I can look back at the problem statement and see $-m^2$ and $m^5$ and determine the quotients' first coefficient has to be to the third power,  but then since there is only three terms in this quotient how do I determine the power of the second and third terms? Thank you.

Comment: When you wrote the $7$, you put it under the $-3$ rather than the $2$.  That "shift" should make you write a $0$ on the right: $-1, 0, -7, 5.$  In other words, the second step didn't happen, because the $2$'s cancel, so a $0$ is written.

Comment: Ah I see thank you.